# Shadow Quality (shadow acne)

Tags: 3d, three.js, shadow

I'm using three.js library and I have some problems with my shadows.
The problem is that my shadows look quite bad.

For example, the [image: Floor has jerky shadows]

And I don't know what to do .. :)

Waiting for your help :D

[EDIT]

An other screenshot to show you my problem..
Here you can see [image: two cubes with bad shadows]

Comment: look at the `shadowBias` parameter. http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/DirectionalLight

Comment: I tried, but it seems nothing goes better.. :/ or should I set a High value for the `shadowBias`?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/YsWGM.jpg

Comment: no it should be something like +/- 0.001

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799206/stripped-shadows-on-collada-objects/30803087#30803087 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545283/shadow-artifacts-on-double-sided-plane/32546348#32546348

Comment: Thank you very much, my shadows are way much better ! The problem now is that I haven't any shadows on the floor anymore..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you WestLangley! :)

I have to use

```
directionalLight.shadowBias = - 0.01;
```

But shadows aren't on the floor anymore, I will work on it!