# Texture / faces deform when shadowMap.enabled is true

Tags: three.js

I have attached two images with the before and after applying shadowMap to the renderer. Notice how the texture / face deforms. What could be causing this and what can I do to remedy the problem?

With shadmowMap disabled:
[image: With shadowMap disabled]

With shadmowMap enabled:
[image: With shadowMap enabled]

This changes depending on the lights camera property values.

Thank you for any replies in advance.

Comment: This artifact is called "Shadow Acne". Experiment with the `shadow.bias`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shadow Quality (shadow acne)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991964/shadow-quality-shadow-acne)

Comment: Yes it appears to be shadow acne. If I edit the shadow bias to get rid of the lines, the shadows appear to offset and create big gaps. My shadow bias value seems to be ok at 2. Although that depends on the how far away the light travels.