# Plane casts shadows on itself

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a simple mesh in Blender, which consist only from one textured plane.
[Blender screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoEFA.png)
I import it in three.js with this code:

```
var texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('models/TexturesCom_Branches0030_1_S.png');
loader.load("models/plant.json", function (geometry, materials) {
    materials.forEach(function (material) {
        material.alphaTest = 0.5;
    });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
    mesh.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
        map: texture2,
        alphaTest: 0.5
    } );
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

That's how mesh looks in three.js: [#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3afy0.jpg)
[#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evN51.png)

As you can see, object casts shadow not only on the ground, but on itself. 
I can turn receiveShadow off, but this is not a solution for me. This problem does not disappear, if I create THREE.PlaneGeometry manually.

Comment: Try `light.shadow.bias = - 0.01`, or similar value, positive or negative.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks, it works. But with bias (-0.000001) there is a problem with verticles, that are very close to the ground. [link](https://i.imgur.com/xKuPhUL.png)

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546348/1461008).

Comment: @WestLangley can you give an answer for this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609577/background-image-will-hidden-when-using-volumetericlightshader-threejs