# How do I set different materials to different groups of indexed faces in a customized mesh in A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm trying to register a custom geometry in A-Frame using THREE.BufferGeometry using two or more indexed groups of faces,
because many vertices will be shared,
and I want to change the mesh AFTER creation,
WITHOUT having to move multiple points and worry about holes appearing in the model.
I want several groups of faces, and I want to assign a different material to EACH GROUP.

I know it might be easier to make nested groups of entities with different materials,
but I am trying to save CPU and GPU time, as well as memory.

ALL the old examples I could find online used THREE.Geometry,
NOT THREE.BufferGeometry. None are working with the current versions, as THREE.Geometry has been depreciated.

I have made eight or nine variations based on the new formatting info I found in the online docs.
I even tried 20+ new versions of the code with the "help" of ChatGPT.

NONE of it's code worked either.

[image]

```
AFRAME.registerGeometry('my-custom-geometry', {
  init: function () {
// Define the vertices of the geometry
const vertices = [
  // First set of five shared points
  -1, 1, 0,
  -1, -1, 0,
  0, -1, 0,
  1, -1, 0,
  1, 1, 0,

  // Second set of five shared points
  -1, 1, 1,
  -1, -1, 1,
  0, -1, 1,
  1, -1, 1,
  1, 1, 1,
];

// Define the indices of the faces
const indices = [
  // Group 1
  0, 1, 2,
  2, 3, 4,
  0, 2, 4,

  // Group 2
  5, 6, 7,
  7, 8, 9,
  5, 7, 9,
];

  // Create a buffer geometry object
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

// Set the attributes of the buffer geometry
const positionAttribute = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3);
geometry.setAttribute('position', positionAttribute);

const indexAttribute = new THREE.Uint16BufferAttribute(indices, 1);
geometry.setIndex(indexAttribute);

// Define the groups of faces
geometry.addGroup(0, 3, 0); // Group 1, material 1
geometry.addGroup(3, 3, 1); // Group 1, material 2
geometry.addGroup(6, 3, 2); // Group 1, material 3
geometry.addGroup(9, 3, 3); // Group 2, material 4
geometry.addGroup(12, 3, 4); // Group 2, material 5
geometry.addGroup(15, 3, 5); // Group 2, material 6

// Register the geometry with A-Frame
this.geometry = geometry;
  }
});

// Define the materials for the groups of faces
const materials = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red' }),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'green' }),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'blue' }),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'yellow' }),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'purple' }),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'orange' }),
];

// Create a mesh object with the registered geometry and materials
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  AFRAME.scenes[0].systems.geometry.getGeometry('my-custom-geometry'),materials);

// Add the mesh object to the scene
AFRAME.scenes[0].object3D.add(mesh);
```

I ALSO tried the following:

```
AFRAME.registerGeometry('custom-geometry', {
  schema: {},
  init: function () {
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

// Define vertices and indices
var vertices = [
  // Define vertices here
];
var indices = [
  // Define indices here
];

// Set vertex and index data
geometry.setIndex(indices);
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

// Create two groups of faces
geometry.addGroup(0, 3, 0);  // Group 1: 3 faces, starting at index 0
geometry.addGroup(3, 3, 1);  // Group 2: 3 faces, starting at index 3

// Define materials for each group
var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });

// Create mesh and apply materials to groups
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [material1, material2]);
mesh.geometry.groups.forEach(function (group) {
  mesh.geometry.addGroup(group.start, group.count, group.materialIndex);
});

// Add mesh to A-Frame entity
this.geometry = mesh.geometry;
  }
});
```

Comment: Don McCurdy, I've seen you address one or two of these issues, but never together in one place. All the examples I've tried seem to conflict with each other when used in conjunction.

Comment: If  points 3&5 can be the same, and points 2&6 can be the same (as in the picture), that would be fine. But I think I will keep them separate so that individual groups and materials can be moved around. I just wondered if the groups had to have separate indexed points.

Comment: It works in THREE.js, but when importing to A-Frame, all materials are flat black.  I CAN change the materials AFTER importing the mesh, but to have to do it each time a mesh is imported, is more trouble. Also, once updated, everything looks like its using a flat shader set to max. (i.e. everything glows in the dark, and there are no shadows), I've tried to force the shader to change, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code piece creates the groups correctly.
If you want your mesh to work properly with lights, you need to:

- compute the normals (otherwise it will be pitch black),
- assign a PBR material like `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial` instead of the `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`.
- set casting and/or shadow receiving via `mesh.castShadow = mesh.receiveShadow = true;`
- work out through plane-casting-shadows issues ([wink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545283/shadow-artifacts-on-double-sided-plane/32546348#32546348), [wink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989568/three-js-plane-doesnt-cast-shadow))

Once you've done it - it should be working:

```js
// define colors for the groups
const colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple", "orange"];

// create the mesh and append it to the scene when its ready
const scene = document.querySelector("a-scene")
scene.addEventListener("loaded", () => {
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    scene.systems.geometry.getOrCreateGeometry({
      "primitive": 'my-custom-geometry'
    }),
    colors.map(color => new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    }))
  );
  mesh.position.set(0, 1, -4);
  mesh.rotation.set(0, Math.PI / 4, 0);
  mesh.castShadow = mesh.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.object3D.add(mesh);
});

// "fix" self - shadowing
const dlight = document.querySelector("#dlight");
dlight.addEventListener("loaded", () => {
  dlight.object3D.children[0].shadow.bias = -0.0001;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerGeometry('my-custom-geometry', {
    init: function() {
      // Define the vertices of the geometry
      const vertices = [
        // First set of five shared points
        -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0,
        0, -1, 0,
        1, -1, 0,
        1, 1, 0,

        // Second set of five shared points
        -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1,
        0, -1, 1,
        1, -1, 1,
        1, 1, 1,
      ];

      // Define the indices of the faces
      const indices = [
        // Group 1
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 4,
        0, 2, 4,

        // Group 2
        5, 6, 7,
        7, 8, 9,
        5, 7, 9,
      ];

      // Create a buffer geometry object
      const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

      // Set the attributes of the buffer geometry
      const positionAttribute = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3);
      geometry.setAttribute('position', positionAttribute);

      const indexAttribute = new THREE.Uint16BufferAttribute(indices, 1);
      geometry.setIndex(indexAttribute);

      // Define the groups of faces
      geometry.addGroup(0, 3, 0); // Group 1, material 1
      geometry.addGroup(3, 3, 1); // Group 1, material 2
      geometry.addGroup(6, 3, 2); // Group 1, material 3
      geometry.addGroup(9, 3, 3); // Group 2, material 4
      geometry.addGroup(12, 3, 4); // Group 2, material 5
      geometry.addGroup(15, 3, 5); // Group 2, material 6
      geometry.computeVertexNormals(); // compute normals

      // Register the geometry with A-Frame
      this.geometry = geometry;
    }
  });
</script>
<a-scene renderer="colorManagement: true">
  <a-entity position="-2 1.5 -2" animation="property: position; to: 2 1.5 -2; dir: alternate; loop: true; dur: 1500; easing: linear">
    <a-sphere radius="0.25" color="yellow" position="0 0 0">></a-sphere>
    <a-light type="point" cast-shadow="true" distance="3"></a-light>
  </a-entity>
  <a-entity id="dlight" light="type:directional; castShadow:true; intensity: 0.2" position="1 1 1"></a-entity>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow="cast: true; receive: true"></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: I'm upvoting for now, but, its the best answer I've seen so far. (Only)  I made a fiddle to show you the color loading error. I can fix it AFTER its made, so I created a timeout function to do it at the end. (the onload flag wasn't working at times.)   https://jsfiddle.net/RKnox/0gnLuqj5/17/

Comment: the material is a property of the `mesh`, not `geometry`. Setting `geometry.material` just adds a property called `material` to the `geometry`. It won't affect anything. If you don't want to mess with custom shaders just make a component which will create a material ([your fiddle with a `multiple-material` component](https://jsfiddle.net/com2r1fe/1/))